# I want to set the following code for SaveAll() in cakephp:

Tags: cakephp

```
array(
'Student' => array(
    'student_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '14',
        (int) 1 => '17',
        (int) 2 => '18'
    ),
    'fee_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '1',
        (int) 2 => '1'
    ),
    'standard_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '1',
        (int) 2 => '1'
    ),
    'section_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '7',
        (int) 1 => '7',
        (int) 2 => '7'
    ),
    'day_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '2015-04-23',
        (int) 1 => '2015-04-23',
        (int) 2 => '2015-04-23'
    ),
    'feeplan_name' => array(
        (int) 0 => '4',
        (int) 1 => '4',
        (int) 2 => '4'
    )
  )
)
```

I want to change the following array code to the format in which **cakephp saveAll()** is applicable. my english is little weak so sory about that tks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error when trying to saveAll ? Couldn't you just use save instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

**EDIT:**

your html should look something like this

```
<input type="text" name="data[Student][0][student_name]">
<input type="text" name="data[Student][1][student_name]">
<input type="text" name="data[Student][2][student_name]">

<input type="text" name="data[Student][0][fee_name]">
<input type="text" name="data[Student][1][fee_name]">
<input type="text" name="data[Student][2][fee_name]">
```

then your array will be

```php
array(
    'Student' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'student_name' => '',
            'fee_name' => ''
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'student_name' => '',
            'fee_name' => ''
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'student_name' => '',
            'fee_name' => ''
        )
    )
)
```

and you will call

```php
$this->Model->saveMany($this->request->data['Student']);
```

Comment: Sorry I am confused how i can changed my array format into the format that you specified. can you send me the code structure by which i can change my array structure to the format you specified tks and Sorry I am beginner at Cakephp .